# Remove Global "use strict' from babel-preset-env

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, gulp-babel

I want to remove the global 'use strict' that babel-preset-env adds with babel 6.x.

I read the other post about es2015.

I've tried the following .babelrc configuration, to no avail:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", {"loose":true}]],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {
      "strict" : false
    }]
  ]
}
```

I do not want to edit the actual file in node_modules as the other post suggested for es2015. That's quite a hack and won't persist.

The only solution so far is to use gulp-iife to wrap every file. Is there really no way to pass an option in my .babelrc file to disable this?

Which plugin in 'env' is even doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to remove it? Strict mode is required for ES modules per spec, and even if you weren’t using ESM, strict mode is great.

Comment: Because a global strict mode applies to everything in that file, including vendor files that might be a part of the concatenated, minified, final output. I plan to put strict mode manually in my iife's, in my code specifically. If I want to use a third party library, that doesn't support strict mode, a global strict mode will break it. Scoped strict modes inside just my own iife's allow my code to conform to strict, and third party libraries to not.

Comment: Example - {options: {presets: [["babel-preset-es2015", { "modules": false }]]}

Answer (score 2):

Set the `modules` option of the `env` preset to `false`:

```
{ 
  "presets": [
       ["env", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

From [babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#modules):

> modules
>   `"amd" | "umd" | "systemjs" | "commonjs" | false`, defaults to `"commonjs"`.
>
> Enable transformation of ES6 module syntax to another module type.
>
> Setting this to false will not transform modules.